# How to get float numbers from a file

Tags: c, data-manipulation

I have this file txt that has these three numbers "4.151120 4.100 7.9999". I am supposed to create a program that reads it and makes some further operations with them. But i cant

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *arq;
    
    arq = fopen("values.txt","r");
    
    float num1, num2, num3;
    
    fscanf(arq,"%.6f %.6f %.6f", &num1, &num2, &num3);
    printf("%.6f %.6f %.6f", num1, num2, num3);
    
    fclose(arq);
    
    return 0;
```

Comment: Exactly how does it "not work"?

Comment: It looks like the only problem is that you need to change `%.6f` to `%f` in the `fscanf` call, as in vonbrand's answer.

Comment: Never use any scanf() function without checking the return code!

Answer (score 5):

It is as simple as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *arq;

    arq = fopen("values.txt", "r");

    float n1, n2, n3;

    if(fscanf(arq, "%f%f%f", &n1, &n2, &n3) != 3)
        fprintf(stderr, "Something's wrong\n");
    else
        printf("Numbers are %f, %f, %f\n", n1, n2, n3);
    
    fclose(arq);
}
```

You don't have to state precision (moot on input), and unless you want to match specific strings between the numbers instead of separating with spaces (the default) you can leave that out.

As a special dispensation, you can omit the `return 0` from `main`, it is implied here.

Comment: Nice tip about not needing the `return 0;` line.

Comment: The `.` is incorrect with [`scanf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) et al.  Using a width can be relevant but usually isn't.  It limits the number of non-blank characters in the numeric field.  If the code were to use `%4f`, then the first number read would be `4.15` and the second `1120` for the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to read the file as a string, and then tokenize the string by spaces.  For each token, then you can format it as a number.  I do not know if that is the best way to do it in c, but it is a viable solution.